# serverless-appsync-plugin 'pipeline' deployment error

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-appsync

I am using serverless to deploy an Appsync API using 'PIPELINE', for use as an API lambda-functions. This plugin https://github.com/sid88in/serverless-appsync-plugin is used to deploy Appsync with the ability to use 'pipeline'. I used the description from the documentation however when I try to do deploy it in myself I have an error:
**Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource GraphQlDsmeInfo**

```
functions:
  graphlql:
    handler: handler.meInfo
    name: meInfo

custom:
  accountId: testId
  appSync:
    name:  test-AppSync
    authenticationType: API_KEY
    mappingTemplates:
      - type: Query
        field: meInfo
        request: 'meInfo-request-mapping-template.vtl'
        response: 'meInfo-response-mapping-template.vtl'
        kind: PIPELINE
        functions:
          - meInfo
    functionConfigurations:
      - dataSource: meInfo
        name: 'meInfo'
        request: 'meInfo-request-mapping-template.vtl'
        response: 'meInfo-response-mapping-template.vtl'
```

Could somebody help me to configure 'serverless-appsync-plugin ' with pipeline kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the [data source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-appsync-datasource.html) used in your function.

It seems you've deployed the handler as Lambda function. If not, first you should have a separate `serverless.yml` config for your Lambda and deploy it. Then you need to attach this Lambda as AppSync data source, so your AppSync config would look like this:

```yaml
custom:
  accountId: testId
  appSync:
    name:  test-AppSync
    authenticationType: API_KEY
    dataSources:
      - type: AWS_LAMBDA
        name: Lambda_Name
        description: 'Lambda Description'
        config:
          lambdaFunctionArn: 'arn:aws:lambda:xxxx'
          serviceRoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::xxxx'
    mappingTemplates:
      - type: Query
        field: meInfo
        request: 'meInfo-request-mapping-template.vtl'
        response: 'meInfo-response-mapping-template.vtl'
        kind: PIPELINE
        functions:
          - meInfo
    functionConfigurations:
      - dataSource: Lambda_Name
        name: 'meInfo'
        request: 'meInfo-request-mapping-template.vtl'
        response: 'meInfo-response-mapping-template.vtl'
```

There is an article which describes the process in details that might be useful: https://medium.com/hackernoon/running-a-scalable-reliable-graphql-endpoint-with-serverless-24c3bb5acb43